# How to evaluate this infinite series arising from a CS problem?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, computer-science

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i\cdot((1-\frac{1}{N!})^{i-1}\cdot\frac{1}{N!})$$

where N is an integer and $N \geq 2$?

I obtained this series from the following problem:

Given a sequence of $N > 2$ unique numbers (not in sorted order), we randomly shuffle the sequence until it becomes sorted in non-decreasing order. What is the expected number of shuffles needed to sort the $N$ numbers?

Intuitively it should be $N!$ since there are $N!$ permutations, but how does one prove this formally (by evaluating the series above, for instance)?

Comment: @T.Bongers Hi but I don't think this is as simple as evaluating a geometric series?

Comment: If you want the _expected number of tries_ until success, you need to multiply the general term by $i$. What you have right now gives you the _probability_ that you will get a success eventually, which is just $1$.

Comment: Oh, but it is a geometric series. The only thing dependent on your index is the exponent.

Comment: Sorry you guys are right - I forgot to add the _i_.

Comment: In that case, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) is the duplicate target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum the series
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot x^{n-1} $$
notice that it's the term-by-term derivative (with respect to $x$) of the geometric series $\sum_n x^n$, which sums to $\frac{1}{1-x}$. So the series above is the derivative of that.

However, in your case, instead of working with series, an easier approach is to say that if you get a success in the first try, then you have $1$ tries until success. Otherwise you have $1$ unsuccessful try so far *and haven't made any progress at all*, so the expected number of *additional* tries you need to make is the same as the original expectation. This gives you the equation
$$ E = 1\cdot\frac{1}{N!} + (1+E)\cdot(1-\frac{1}{N!}) $$
which is easily solved, giving $E=N!$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, especially the last part which completely avoids the use of series.

Answer (score 2):

Since N is a constant, we can factor the $\dfrac1{N!}$ out. Let $r=1-\dfrac1{N!}$, so we need to compute $S=1+2r+3r^2+\cdots$. Let $X=1+r+r^2+\cdots$. Note that $X=S+rS+r^2S+\cdots=S^2$. By the geometric series formula, $S=\dfrac1{1-r}$, so $X=\dfrac1{(1-r)^2}$.  Plugging in the expression for r gives that $X=\dfrac{1}{1-\left(1-\dfrac1{N!}\right)^2}=N!^2$. Then multiplying by the $\dfrac1{N!}$ that was factored out gives the full sum as $N!$